# Populate a column ONLY if there is a value on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a specific value in one column only if the value on the other column is not blank. My current code returns the value for all the column regardless of if its blank or not.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': [12, 34, 54, 23, 12, 43, 53, 12, 43, 12],
        'col2': ['USD', 'CAD', 'USD', 'USD', 'CAD', 'USD', 'USD', 
                 'EURO', 'USD', 'USD'],
    }
)
```

Here's my code:

```
# Set date/time reply and empty column 
def add_days_to_date(date, days):
    subtracted_date = pd.to_datetime(date) + timedelta(days=days)
    subtracted_date = subtracted_date.strftime("%m-%d")
    return subtracted_date 
def replied_sent_date(date):
    return f"Opened {date} need update {add_days_to_date(date, 1)}"
```

```
date = datetime.date.today() 
date_format = date.strftime('%m-%d')

df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda _:" ", axis=1)

df.loc[df['col1'] != '', 'col3'] = f"Opened {date_format} will need an update {add_days_to_date(date, 30)}"
```

Desired output:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': [12, 34, 54, 23, 12, 43, 53, 12, 43, 12],
        'col2': ['USD', 'CAD', 'USD', 'USD', 'CAD', 'USD', 'USD', 
                 'EURO', 'USD', 'USD'],
        'col3': [*Look at note below*]
    }
)
```

** "col3" would output "f"Opened {date_format} will need an update {add_days_to_date(date, 30)}" for every cell in which there exists a value for col1.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you add an typical example and a desired output ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried to do both, let me know if it is clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Jose please provide a **meaningful** example, there is no missing value there. Also provide the **explicit matching output**

Comment: Well the issue is that there are no blank columns, but when I export to excel I run into the issue that, if `col1` shows the last value on B124, `col3` will populate the whole column and not stop on B124. Not sure on how to exemplify that.

Comment: @JoseDanielRojas the last value in line B124 is empty?